# can´t execute a command line on Linux with a php file from Browser

Tags: php, linux, command, execute, shell-exec

I installed a program on my debian server. I can execute it with: `./programm` and the result is a wall of text and it is creating a HTML file with this text.

Now I am trying to execute the `./programm` from a browser with PHP. The apache user is www-data and I added execute rights for this program.

I wrote a little PHP script:

test.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

shell_exec('./programm 2>&1');
?>
```

The path is okay because I have all files in the same directory for testing.  With the user www-data i execute in the shell:

```
php test.php
```

Results in a wall of text and the created HTML file (it's working).

Now i try it from browser:

```
"Aborted"
```

Why isn't it working?

Comment: aborted is not a php error. that'd be something your programm is spitting out.

Comment: How do you run it as `www-data`???

Comment: I don't know that this would fix the Aborted error but you probably want `echo shell_exec('./programm 2>&1');`.

Comment: PHP can be configured to enforce a time limit for response or kill the process.

Comment: AbraCadaver: You can log in with su www-data to test it .

Comment: Ryan Jones: i have the echo in my sourcecode. I forgot it to write it here down. But it is not solving my problem. 
PauL: can you please explain your comment? You mean that i get with a Browser Aborted message, because the php connection timed out ?